# Get timezone offset for a given location

Tags: php, timezone, location, dst

Is it possible in PHP to get the timezone offset for a given location? E.g. when given the location "Sydney/Australia" to get the timezone offset as "+1100". Bonus would be for this function the keep daylight savings in mind (i.e. it's aware of daylight savings and adjusts the offset according).

Comment: Are you trying to display date/time in a given timezone?

Comment: Do you mean official timezone names, or any location in the world?

Comment: @david. I'm storing UTC's and I want to be able to convert that time stamp to any local time.

Comment: @pekka. Offcial time zone names are good enough.

Comment: @Luke I thought so - then you don't need to calculate the offset and do the arithmetic yourself. See my answer below.

Comment: @david. That seems indeed as a slightly nicer way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry about some confusion. When in the question I asked for '+1100' I didn't mean it that literal. Just an integer 11 would suffice of course. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display a local date/time you can use the following, where 'Europe/Berlin' would be replaced with the user's timezone.

```
$date = new DateTime($value);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/datetimezone) class.

```
<?php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");
$offset = $timezone->getOffset(new DateTime("now")); // Offset in seconds
echo ($offset < 0 ? '-' : '+').round($offset/3600).'00'; // prints "+1100"
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you need "+1100" (rather than a decimal representation) but you can use this:

```
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
$offset = $dt->getOffset()/60/60; // 11

$hours = intval($offset);
$minutes = str_pad((string)($offset - $hours) * 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
echo $hours.$minutes; // 1100
```

Replace `null` with `'2010-10-01'` and you'll get `1000`