# timezone with DST handling by PHP

Tags: php, datetime, utc, dst, timezone-offset

I am working on a calendar application. In this users from different time-zones create/view events.
I am thinking to follow below method to save event time in UTC and display them in user's local time. Note: user has their preferred timezone setting.

**To save event start time as UTC timestamp:**

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone( $user_timezone_name );
$utcOffset = $timezone->getOffset( new DateTime( $event_start_time_string_local ) );
$event_start_timestamp_local = maketime( $event_start_time_string_local );
//Now add/subtract $utcOffset to/from $event_start_timestamp_local to get event's start  //time  timestamp in UTC and save this result in DB.
```

**To get event start time in user's timezone:**

```
date_default_timezone_set( $user_timezone_name );
$eventTimeLocalTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $event_start_timestamp_in_UTC );
```

Where:

```
user_timezone_name is user's timezone setting.
event_start_time_string_local is event's start time string in local/civil time.
event_start_timestamp_in_UTC is event's start time timestamp in UTC.
```

**My questions:**

- Whether the PHP APIs used above take care of DST for all regions?
- The DST time itself changes in different years, how does PHP gets information about this? do we need to upgrade PHP? If so do we need to upgrade all or particular PHP library?

References:
 - [does-phps-date-default-timezone-set-adjust-to-daylight-saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660240/does-phps-date-default-timezone-set-adjust-to-daylight-saving?rq=1)
 - [get-timezone-offset-for-a-given-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910500/get-timezone-offset-for-a-given-location?rq=1)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're way too overcomplicating this. To convert between two timezones using `DateTime`, do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // YOUR timezone, of the server

$date = new DateTime($input, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo')); // USER's timezone
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This converts from a user's local timezone to UTC. To go the other way around, to display the time in the user's local time, swap the two timezones.

Yes, PHP takes care of DST. The necessary conversion rules are part of the PHP installation. You can keep them up to date by updating PHP, or by updating the [timezonedb](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).

Comment: Updating the timezonedb is a regular task, needed several times per year, because every time any country does a change it gets an update - and this happens quite frequently.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use this

Comment: Why do we need to call 'date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata')' at the starting?

Comment: I think I can't use $input as unix epoch timestamp for DateTime(). Currently, in my system we save events time as unix epoch timestamp, can I use the same with DateTime()?
Basically, is it possible to work with unix epoch timestamps instead of date string?

Comment: You can use `'@12345...'` for UNIX time stamps.

Comment: @Krishna And you need to set your server's timezone correctly for *all* date/time functions. If you've already done this correctly before, ignore it.

Comment: @deceze , thank you. But DateTime doc. at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php says "The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00)"
--That means we can't pass the timezone name?Does your code behave same if we pass the Unix epoch timestamp?
Thanks

Comment: @deceze or UNIX timestamp is always UTC?
I thought even local time can be represented in UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @Krishna A UNIX timestamp is defined as *seconds since 1970 UTC*. The timestamp is timezone-free, but if anything it's UTC. You can format in into a "local" time as shown above.

Comment: DateTime requires $input in a valid format. But I have the $input as an array(like $input['year'], $input['month'], $input['day'], $input['hour'], $input['min'], $input['sec'] are set). Is there any easy way to convert this in to valid format which DateTime accepts? Thank you

Comment: @deceze I think I will format as 'Y-m-d H:i:s' and pass to DateTime()

Comment: 1) Please read again the question/subject of this thread
2) DST is not automatically handled by just setting the PHP timezone

Comment: Oh, I wish time (or the concept of it) didn't exist!

Answer (score 10):

Yes php api takes into account DST. Most of the time you can safely perform time conversion the way deceze had shown. The problem is that it is not always possible/doable or makes sense. Consider below example - in Poland (in 2013) on Oct 27th at 3am your clock is moved back one hour to switch to standard time (offset UTC+01:00) on March 31st at 2am clock is adjusted forward by 1h to switch to summer time(offset UTC+02:00). Let's now see how 'real time' ticks in Grenwich/UTC and how conversion by PHP from Europe/Warsaw to UTC works:

```
Europe/Warsaw time   offset  UTC                    php2utc conversion   php offset
2013-10-27 01:00:00    +2    2013-10-26 23:00:00    2013-10-26 23:00:00  +2
2013-10-27 01:30:00    +2    2013-10-26 23:30:00    2013-10-26 23:30:00  +2
2013-10-27 02:00:00    +2    2013-10-27 00:00:00    2013-10-27 01:00:00  +1  *
2013-10-27 02:30:00    +2    2013-10-27 00:30:00    2013-10-27 01:30:00  +1  *
2013-10-27 02:59:00    +2    2013-10-27 00:59:00    2013-10-27 01:59:00  +1  *
     3am -> 2am .....................................summer time changes to standard(winter) time @3am we subtract 1h so 3am becomes 2am
2013-10-27 02:00:00    +1    2013-10-27 01:00:00    2013-10-27 01:00:00  +1
2013-10-27 02:30:00    +1    2013-10-27 01:30:00    2013-10-27 01:30:00  +1
2013-10-27 03:00:00    +1    2013-10-27 02:00:00    2013-10-27 02:00:00  +1  
2013-10-27 03:30:00    +1    2013-10-27 02:30:00    2013-10-27 02:30:00  +1
```

As you can see between 2am-3am there is no way PHP can know 'which' hour (from before/after adjustment) it is hence cannot reliably convert.
Hope this helps someone in his/her deliberations ;-)

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm trying to write a unit test for.  Presumably the DateTimeZone object includes the DST alteration.  How can I force it one way or the other?  Is there some consistency (like if I specify a time in the hour, of overlap, it'll always opt for the DST time), also what about the missing hour.  In the above example, there is no local time, March 31st 2.30am in Poland (that would be 3.30am UTC+2).  Presumably there is a detailed spec for this somewhere.  Any idea where?

Comment: Thanks for that table. Within this one problematic hour, one cannot enter the CEST values, as they are always handeled as CET. Even when the CEST-timezone is explicitly given. I solved this by detecting the DST-change (with `format('I')`) and in that case I create a DateTime with an hour early, convert it to UTC and add that missing hour afterwards. Now my UTC-database has its hourly values without holes or duplicate timestamps.