# Compare Timestamp with another Timestamp object

Tags: java, timestamp

I'm newer to Java. I'm using two Timestamp objects `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. I want to check whether the `dateFrom` is 45 days **earlier** than `dateTo`. I used this code fragment to compare this
`if(dateFrom.compareTo(dateTo) < 45)
{
  // do the action;
}`

I'm confusing with the `45` given in the code. Can I expect the correct result. will it meets my result.

Comment: Should be interesting for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Comment: Why don't you run the code and check it yourself?! Would have been faster and you'd have figured out the result yourself.

Comment: The usual return value of `.compareTo(...)` is a value "less than zero for less than, equal to zero for equal, and greater than zero for greater than" and I do not believe that you can count on getting the exact difference amount by using this function.  Rather, you should use the idiom `dateFrom.compareTo(dateTo.add("45 days"))` except with actual code instead of pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compareTo()` returns a value of -1, 0 or 1, depending on the result.

What you want to do is

```
long result = dateTo.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 45) - dateFrom.getTime();
if(result >= 0) {
 System.out.println("dateFrom is 45 days or more before dateTo");
else {
 System.out.println("dateFrom is less than 45 days before dateTo");
}
```

This is rather ugly though. Is there a specific reason you're not using a `Calendar`?

Comment: It is risky to add seconds manually. There are some events that altered the timeline, you know that right?

Comment: Yes, we've all read the famous answer by Jon Skeet. I think it's safe to assume that OP will not be working with these extreme edge cases. If he does, then he should use an actual good way to work with time like Joda Time or `Calendar`.

Comment: @Jeroen: 1000 * 60 * 24 * 45 is not number of milliseconds in 45 days - 45*24*3600*1000 is the right number

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about it a bit logically. First of all you need to get to a timestamp which is 45 days before the `dateTo` date. Time has various units (seconds, minutes, hours, days) so just checking `< 45` is meaningless in this case. The `compareTo()` method is just there for ordering to know if a timestamp is before or after the other.

You could first create a `Calendar` for the timestamps, and [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) `dateFrom` by 45 days. Then you can use the [before()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check if `dateFrom` is before `dateTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Joda Time or Calendar class(add 45 days to dateFrom, compare the result with dateTo).

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
Date dateFrom ="your from date";                 
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal .setTime(dateFrom);            
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 45);
Date expireDate = cal.getTime();
Date dateTo = new Date();
if(dateTo.after(expireDate)){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Timestamp in Java is number of milliseconds from UNIX Epoch - change 45 days to number of milliseconds (45d=45*24h=45*24*3600s=45*24*3600*1000ms) so if:

```
(time_B + 45*24*3600*1000) >= time_A
```

it means that time_B is 45 days (or more) 'further' in time that time_A

Of course you can use JodaTime and other libs too.

Comment: It is risky to add seconds manually. There are some events that altered the timeline, you know that right?

Comment: Yes I am aware of Timezones, daylight saving issues and so on - some of these issues cannot even be solved using fancy libs and this will work for most of the cases.

Comment: Hey guys - why so many downvotes? Selected answer has incorrect calculation of miliseconds within 45 days and mine has correct one - so what is that all about?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, however your answer is not entirely correct, we talked about that earlier.

Comment: @Silviu: I was refering to directly to you but in general ;-). I am aware this answer does not even touch the problems that might arise from date/time operations. I was just curious why I was downvoted several times - but nevermind. There are many pots describing potential issues on SO - for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698779/timezone-with-dst-handling-by-php/19004000#19004000