# Generate proper date time accordingly daylight saving time

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need a little help. Let's say I have two tables: values and periods. In the values table i save values for every day and for each hour.
The format is like that:

```
ID | Value | Hour | PeriodID | Datetime
```

The PeriodID references to the other table (periods) where I save the object id and the local date in format YYYY-mm-dd.

In the values table the Datetime must be a centralized time for example CET so i can compare different object for each hour.

For that reason i have a PHP GMT function which generates from a given date (Y-m-d H:i:s) new date time, based on the object timezone:

```
function gmt($date, $timezone) {
    $h = abs($timezone);
    $hm = $h * 60; 
    $ms = $hm * 60;
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $gmt_timestamp = ($timezone >= 0) ? $timestamp+($ms) : $timestamp-($ms);
    return gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $gmt_timestamp);
}
```

Unfortunately i have a problem when the daylight saving time changes. In that situation i have missing (2016-10-30 02:00:00) and duplicate hours (2016-10-31 01:00:00), which is wrong:

```
11910345 | 4.0 | 01.00 | 300476 | 2016-10-30 01:00:00
11910346 | 3.0 | 02.00 | 300476 | 2016-10-30 03:00:00
...
11910363 | 2.0 | 22.00 | 300476 | 2016-10-30 23:00:00
11910364 | 2.0 | 23.00 | 300476 | 2016-10-31 00:00:00
11910365 | 2.0 | 24.00 | 300476 | 2016-10-31 01:00:00
11910366 | 1.0 | 00.00 | 300477 | 2016-10-31 01:00:00
```

How can i regenerate the new date which will produce me continuously datetimes without missing or duplicate dates ?

Thanks in advice

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/13698860/1628790?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielHeming for your response. My way for converting the the datetime based on a timezone is almost the same, just i get the timezone as an integer (-1, 0, +1 ... ). That what is me disturbing is the duplicate or missing hours. Is there any trick to do that ?

Comment: What you could do is check if the date had DST or not. As I live in Brazil, now it's DST, so: `$date = new DateTime('now' , new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));`. When I format using `I` (capital i) `$date->format('I')`, it's echo `1`. When I change for a date without DST, as `$date = new DateTime('2016-05-23' , new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));`, it's output `0`

Comment: Remember also, consider the DST as a change of your timezone, not just the plus 1 of hour. So if your timezone is -3, and it's DST now, the timezone must be -2.